# nw.js + angular2: System is not defined

Tags: angular, systemjs, nw.js

After updating my app from nw.js 0.13.0 and angular2 2.0.0-beta.9 to nw.js 0.15.0-rc1 and angular2 2.0.0-rc.1 I get the following error while loading:

```
index.html:1 Error: chrome-extension://cncjajlacahjmkcnajkoclbmdkepcfij/app/dist/main.js:17
})(System, System);
   ^
ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at chrome-extension://cncjajlacahjmkcnajkoclbmdkepcfij/app/dist/main.js:17:4
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
Evaluating chrome-extension://cncjajlacahjmkcnajkoclbmdkepcfij/app/dist/main.js
Error loading chrome-extension://cncjajlacahjmkcnajkoclbmdkepcfij/app/dist/main.js
```

The error is generated in the following line:

```
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

I've tried nearly every solution I found online but until now I was not able to resolve this problem. When I run it in the browser everthing works as expected.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact problem you describe.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm sorry. We switched from nw.js and system.js to electron and webpack so i was not investigating this problem anymore.